# Do databricks git integration supports notebook deletion feature?

Tags: git, azure-devops, version-control, databricks, azure-databricks

I started to explore git integration with databricks and was successful to set it in DEV and than through CICD I was able to take changes to QA and PROD but I am little confuse regarding notebook deletion. Suppose my Notebook-A was integrated with Git but I got a new version of it so decided to delete that notebook. So my question here is, will the Notebook-A automatically get deleted from Azure Devops? We usually save and create a pull request from our notebook to bring changes to git but If my notebook is deleted than how is it possible that git will know that my notebook no longer exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my observation as per my repro:

> Will the Notebook-A automatically get deleted from Azure Devops?

If you delete the Notebook-A from Azure Databricks workspace, it will not automatically get deleted from Azure Devops. You need to manually delete it from Azure Devops.

> We usually save and create a pull request from our notebook to bring changes to git but If my notebook is deleted than how is it possible that git will know that my notebook no longer exists?

Unfortunately, Azure devops will not know that the notebooks if it deleted are not untill or unless if you saved the changes.

**Important points to note:**

- It will overwrite all the notebooks if already exists with the same
  name.
- It will add notebooks if it doesn’t exist.
- If notebooks are renamed in devops then it will just add a new notebook and won’t delete the old one.
- It will create folders if it doesn’t exist.